# "Run to line feature" while debugging in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Is there a run-to-line feature in the default Firefox debugger?

I use Firefox on Ubuntu. While debugging a block of code, I right-click on a line hoping to find some option to that effect, instead I get this:

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with adding a breakpoint and then running? It will stop at the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox DevTools do not offer this feature yet. There's an [enhancement request filed for it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=878308), though.

Until the feature is available within the tools, you can mimic its behavior by setting a breakpoint and then continuing the script execution, as DavidPostill wrote.